# CSS - How to completely center one box in another one?

Tags: css, margin

I am learning css as beginner and doing some basic tests. My question is: given the css below how can I position the box2 in exactly the middle of the box1?

```
.box1 {
  background: black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.box2 {
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

At the beginning I thought giving box2 a margin auto so the box2 would be in equal distance from top and bottom but I get this result.

[image]

It looks like it sets the margin auto for left and right but not for top and bottom.

So if I give a margin top myself it works like this.

[image]

Code:

```
.box2 {
   margin: 20px auto;
}
```

How can I do so the box2 is completely centered in the box1?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box1 {
background: black;
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
margin: auto;
}

.box2 {
height:300px;
width:300px;
background: red;
position:relative;
left:12.5%;
top:12.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
<div class="box2">

</div>
</div>
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box1 {
background: black;
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items: center;
}

.box2 {
height:300px;
width:300px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
<div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `flexbox`

```css
.box1 {
  background: black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box2 {
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.box1 {
  position:relative;
  background: black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.box2 {
  position:absolute;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background: red;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wh4yqk2y/